# Run multiple commands services in yml file when docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I want to run multiple command when I docker-compose up this service, but always failed

Win 10, Powershell, docker: 2.4.0.0, Engine: 19.03.13, Compose:1.27.4

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    cypress:
        container_name: tax_t_cypress
        image: cypress/included:5.4.0
        command: bash -c "npm i cypress-file-upload@5.0.3" && cypress run
        volumes:
          - ./:/tax
        working_dir: /tax
        environment:
          - CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://nginx:8888
        depends_on: 
          - webpack
```

It will error

```
You passed: npm i cypress-file-upload@5.0.3
The error was: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

If I use single command like `command: cypress run`, It's okay, But I really need install the dependency first in this image, How can I run multiple command in yml successfully.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to install something on the image, you should do it on the image level, by writing a dockerfile and referencing it in your docker compose.

your dockerfile could be

```
FROM cypress/included:5.4.0
RUN npm i cypress-file-upload@5.0.3
CMD ["cypress" , "run"]
```

in your docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    cypress:
        container_name: tax_t_cypress
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ./:/tax
        working_dir: /tax
        environment:
          - CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://nginx:8888
        depends_on: 
          - webpack
```

Comment: Also, you can put all the commands you want to run on a script, load it to the container image, and configure it as the `ENTRYPOINT` of the container. Though in this specific case, @Umair's answer is exactly what you need.